# Parse files to get a specific constant and its integer to store into an array

Tags: bash

I have several Exception classes like this one (is PHP, but it doesnt matter right now):

```
class FileNotFoundException extends OtherException {
    const DEFAULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE = 159;

    public function __construct($code=self::DEFAULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE) {
            parent::__construct($code);
    }

}
```

## The Problem

I need to get the error codes from all files to store them into an array (the index is the error code, and the value is the constant name) to just print it with order.

### Tips

1. All the files are `.php` files
2. The constant error codes are always like `const DEFAULT_[A-Z_]_ERROR_CODE = [0-9]+;`
3. I tried to be stored in an array like this `array[159]="DEFAULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE";`

## What have I done

What I tried to do --with my little bashscripting knowledge-- is a **script** that parses all this php exception files and gets only the constant `DEFAULT_[...]_ERROR_CODE = "number";`

This is my **script.sh** trying to get it:

```
#! /bin/bash

sed -n "s/const \(DEFAULT[A-Z_]*\) = \([0-9]*\);/$array[\2]=\1;/p" $1
```

And if I do this:
`script.sh <  FileNotFoundException.php`

It outputs `[159]=DEFAULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE;`

Then I tried to put a variable "array" in there, like this:

```
eval('$array(`sed -n "s/const \(DEFAULT[A-Z_]*\) = \([0-9]*\);/$array[\2]=\1;/p" $1`)')
```

and several other combinations, but with no success.

### Why I'm posting this in stackOverflow

I wanted to know if is possible to solve it and **how**, or if there is other way easier to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Could the multiple levels of apostrophes (`'`) in the `eval` line be causing a problem?

Comment: The more internal are [grave accents][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent] but stackoverflow doesnt allow me to put it without losing the format to the code. So I used an apostrophe.

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code for more information about putting literal backtick (grave accent) characters in code examples. You can also indent the line by four spaces instead of using the backtick (`) character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "$" in front of `array`:

```
#! /bin/bash
sed -n "s/.*const \(DEFAULT[A-Z_]*\) = \([0-9]*\);.*/array[\2]=\1;/p" $1
```

Now it will output `array[159]=DEFAULT_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE;` which can be eval'd to set array elements:

```
eval "$(find yourdir -name '*.php' -exec cat {} + | yourscript)"
```

(I also added some `.*`s to the sed expression so that appending a `$(rm -ri /)` to the line in the php script won't cause you to evaluate it.)

Comment: thanks, ill try it tomorrow (at work), and if it works i'll accept your answer